# Select the register with not null value in a column with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next results with the following query:

[image]

```
SELECT `id_booking`, `id_task`, `type`, `date`
FROM (SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 1 AS `type`, `date_in` AS `date`
    FROM `booking`
    WHERE `date_in` <= '2016-10-24'
    AND `date_in` >= '2016-10-14'
    AND `status` = 'accepted'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 2 AS `type`, `date_out` AS `date`
    FROM `booking`
    WHERE `date_out` <= '2016-10-24'
    AND `date_out` >= '2016-10-14'
    AND `status` = 'accepted'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `booking_id` AS `id_booking`, `id` AS `id_task`, `id_type` AS `type`, `date` AS `date`
    FROM `task`
    WHERE `date` <= '2016-10-24'
    AND `date` >= '2016-10-14')
    AS `tasks`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

I'm trying to get the register with not null `id_task` when the `id_booking` and `type` are duplicated but if I introduce the clause GROUP BY I just can get the first one register with `id_task` = NULL.

Is there any possibility to take the register with not null value between multiple registers grouped by GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complex ...

but from the result of the select union you should select only the id whit duplicated rows and for this only these with not null type

```
SELECT `id_booking`, `id_task`, `type`, `date`
  FROM (SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 1 AS `type`, `date_in` AS `date`
      FROM `booking`
      WHERE `date_in` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date_in` >= '2016-10-14'
      AND `status` = 'accepted'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 2 AS `type`, `date_out` AS `date`
      FROM `booking`
      WHERE `date_out` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date_out` >= '2016-10-14'
      AND `status` = 'accepted'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `booking_id` AS `id_booking`, `id` AS `id_task`, `id_type` AS `type`, `date` AS `date`
      FROM `task`
      WHERE `date` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date` >= '2016-10-14') AS `tasks`
  where  (`id_booking`,  `type`) in (  select `id_booking`,  `type` FROM 
            (SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 1 AS `type`, `date_in` AS `date`
                FROM `booking`
                WHERE `date_in` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date_in` >= '2016-10-14'
                AND `status` = 'accepted'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 2 AS `type`, `date_out` AS `date`
                FROM `booking`
                WHERE `date_out` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date_out` >= '2016-10-14'
                AND `status` = 'accepted'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `booking_id` AS `id_booking`, `id` AS `id_task`, `id_type` AS `type`, `date` AS `date`
                FROM `task`
                WHERE `date` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date` >= '2016-10-14') t
                group by  `id_booking`,  `type`
                having count(*) > 1         
    ) 
  and id_task is not null 

union  

SELECT `id_booking`, `id_task`, `type`, `date`
  FROM (SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 1 AS `type`, `date_in` AS `date`
      FROM `booking`
      WHERE `date_in` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date_in` >= '2016-10-14'
      AND `status` = 'accepted'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 2 AS `type`, `date_out` AS `date`
      FROM `booking`
      WHERE `date_out` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date_out` >= '2016-10-14'
      AND `status` = 'accepted'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `booking_id` AS `id_booking`, `id` AS `id_task`, `id_type` AS `type`, `date` AS `date`
      FROM `task`
      WHERE `date` <= '2016-10-24'
      AND `date` >= '2016-10-14') AS `tasks`
  where  (`id_booking`,  `type`) in (  select `id_booking`,  `type` FROM 
            (SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 1 AS `type`, `date_in` AS `date`
                FROM `booking`
                WHERE `date_in` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date_in` >= '2016-10-14'
                AND `status` = 'accepted'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `id` AS `id_booking`, null AS `id_task`, 2 AS `type`, `date_out` AS `date`
                FROM `booking`
                WHERE `date_out` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date_out` >= '2016-10-14'
                AND `status` = 'accepted'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `booking_id` AS `id_booking`, `id` AS `id_task`, `id_type` AS `type`, `date` AS `date`
                FROM `task`
                WHERE `date` <= '2016-10-24'
                AND `date` >= '2016-10-14') t
                group by  `id_booking`,  `type`
                having count(*) = 1         
    ) 
  and id_task is  null 

ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: Hi! I'm so sorry but I don't understand the reply. The result which I posted comes from two different tables with two different date column in one of them. That's the reason because I do the UNION. How can I apply your solution with this table structure?

Comment: @DavidLombardía   i'm  sorry i have take only a brief look at your code  .. anyway i have update the answer referring to you complete query

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still having problems: the first one is I get the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" and the other one is I can have just the registers with id_task not null with this SQL but I want to have the registers with id_task not null just in case I have multiple registers with the same id_booking and type. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLombardía  .  the derived table alias is added .. and the query should retunrn the rows with more then one same  id_booking, and type  and on this result should filter only the rows with id_task not null.

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge! With this last query I can get all the task with duplicate `id_booking` and `type`. But if I have one register for one `id_booking`/`type` with id_task = null I need to show you in the results too. Do you know how can I complete the query for that? Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean one rows not with id_booking and type not duplicated and  id_task = null?

Comment: inmean now I can get all the rows with COUNT > 1 and id_task NOT NULL but I need the rows with COUNT = 1 and id_task NULL

Comment: @DavidLombardía   . well added  the union for the count=1 and id_task is null .. hope this is useful ..